# Postgrest Script \Copy Canceled by User Request

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am newbie to postgres and I am finding some difficulties to understand what's going on. I am working with a client's DB in postgres, the job is to extract some tables into CSV and upload it through FTP. The thing is that if the table exports more than few thousands of rows the command stops and throws the error : `ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request`

Here is the command I am running:`psql -c "\COPY (select * from <table_name> ) TO 'C:\\Users\<user_name>\<file_name>.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;" -U <user> <db_name>`

Is there anyway to find what's causing the error? the feedback psql returns is too vague

Comment: How long is the query running, it may be timing out against the host environment ?

Comment: it takes 5-10 secs, that was my first thought but which flag might be raising the cancel?

Comment: also, the query works fine, but the copy command does not

Comment: I believe its more likely to be an environment issue being Windows, not postgres ?

Comment: My bet is that the problem is something regarding stdout. The docs say that \copy basically uses "copy <table> to STDOUT". and if i try to do that it gives the same error